# Breaking a path, in 2 integrals

Tags: integration, vector-fields, parametrization

> Let $\overrightarrow V, \Gamma$, be a vectorial field and a path such that:
>
> $$\overrightarrow V=-(x^2+y^2)\overrightarrow i-(x^2-y^2)\overrightarrow j$$
>
> and
>
> $$\Gamma=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2=4, y < 0\}\cup \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}| (x-1)^2+y^2=1, y \geq0\}$$

I know that: $\int_{\Gamma}\overrightarrow V d\overrightarrow r=\int_{\Gamma}Pdx+Qdy$

$P(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$

$Q(x,y)=y^2-x^2$

I'm going to use this parametrization to calculate this:

$x(t)=2\cos t$

$y(t)=2\sin t$

$t\in[\pi,2\pi]$

But that is only for the first part of the path can I calculate the first part of the path with a parametrization and the second one of the path with another parametrization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is in fact the union of two different ones: the lower semicircle $\;x^2+y^2=4\;$ and the upper semicircle $\;(x-1)^2+y^2=1\;$ . For the first one you can parametrize (in the positive direction)

$$\Gamma_1: r_1(t)=(2\cos t,\,2\sin t)\;,\;\;t\in[\pi,2\pi]\;$$

and the second one

$$\Gamma_2: r_2(t)=(1+\cos t,\,\sin t)\;,\;\;t\in[0,\pi]$$

Usually paths given are path connected, yet this one isn't....anyway, now you can integrate on each separatedly.